# Is hydrochloric acid or sulfuric acid more corrosive to titanium?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, transition-metals, corrosion

Which acid is more corrosive to titanium at 20 to 30 °C and similar concentrations: hydrochloric acid $\ce{HCl}$ or sulfuric acid $\ce{H2SO4}$?

I found some info on [AZoMaterials — Titanium - Corrosion by Acids](https://www.azom.com/amp/article.aspx?ArticleID=1240), but it was not exactly apples to apples.

Also, if the acid concentrations are very low (say, less than 0.01%), which one will have worse long term effects on the metal?